# Multivariable Limits and Paths

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

No, I am not asking for someone to explain how the paths method of showing a limit is nonexistent is correct. I am actually asking about the reverse which I am conjecturing:

---

Let the limit of f(x,y) approach L as (x,y) approaches (a,b).

Let y = g(x), for any g(x) in the Reals, such that g(x) obeys the domain restrictions of the function f on y.

Does this necessitate that g(x) approaches b?

---

I am not asking whether g(x) satisfies the problem, I am asking whether the two dimension limit implies that every one dimensional limit of a certain form approaches b.

Comment: See [*Discontinuities and smooth curves in n-space*](http://people.math.sc.edu/nyikos/smooth.pdf) by Peter J. Nyikos.

Comment: Limits aren't discontinuous; functions are. Limits don't approach anything; they either exist and equal something, or don't exist. You're welcome.

Comment: Thank you zhw, but be more clear in your attitudes for future comments

Comment: @Dave, thank you very much

Comment: I have no idea what that means, and I have no idea what you're asking in your question.

Comment: @zhw See my answer in response to Dave's comment

Answer (score 0):

As Dave commented and linked to, there is a paper which shows the following (but even the author was unsure if anyone else had proved it)

---

If the limit of a real-valued function on $ R^{2} $ exists at a point p, then it will also be the limit along any smooth curve through p.

---